# getline is assigning no value to a string object

Tags: c++, runtime-error, getline

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//YOUR_CODE
string word;

cout << "enter a word: ";
getline(cin, word);
int middle = word.length();
middle = middle/2;
if(middle % 2 == 0)
{
    middle = word.length();
    middle = (middle/2)+1;
    floor (middle);
}
int last = word.length();
cout << word[0] << word.at(middle) << word.at(last);
}
```

I'm not sure why the getline is not working. Checking through the book I'm using, and debugger hasn't helped. Does anyone know what is wrong with it? In debugger, it says value: < not accessible >. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `floor(middle)` supposed to do when you don't assign it anywhere?

Comment: Where is `getvalue` in your program?

Comment: What does the tag `trygetvalue` mean?

Comment: Middle is equal to the length of the string (word)/2. I floor it in the if statement because my professor wants it to do that and then output it in the cout statement.

Comment: I don't need getvalue (to my knowledge) and trygetvalue means I tried to get a value. Have any idea why word isn't being assigned a value?

Comment: You wrote in the question "I'm not sure why the getvalue is not working". What does that refer to?

Comment: I meant getline, not getvalue.

Comment: You don't need to use `floor` when the variable is an integer. It only makes sense for floating point.

Comment: And even if you did need to use it, you have to assign it somewhere, e.g. `middle = floor(middle);`.

Comment: Not to be picky, but `int main()` should have a corresponding `return` statement... It doesn't change anything, but please, adhere to the standard.

Comment: You claim that `getline` is not working.  Why is this your assumption?  What have you done to verify this claim?  Have you tried printing the value of `word` *immediately* after calling `getline`?  Have you tried simplifying your code to isolate the problem?

Comment: Give him a little break -- he did try using a debugger, which is far more than most posters here do. He just didn't understand the output.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with the assignment to `word`. The problem is `word.at(last)`. String positions run from `0` to `length-1` (just like arrays). Since `last` is `word.length()` you're trying to access a character outside that range. Try:

```
last = word.length()-1;
```

Comment: Ah, that worked. Thanks! Do you know why it is length()-1? Apparently, it was in my book but I didn't understand it.

Comment: Because positions start at 0. If the word is 6 characters long, the valid positions are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.